# PPA latest stable version apache, mariadb, python, php, phpmyadmin in linux mint 20.3

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, ppa

I am a linux novice and I am looking for stable repositories (PPA) with the latest stable apache, mariadb, python, php, phpmyadmin packages that I can easily update with the APT command. I don't like updating from tar.gz packages. Someone would like to help me?

Answer (score 2):

The latest stable releases of these softwares that are fully supported under Linux Mint 20.3 are *exactly* these that you get when you simply use the Mint 20.3 packages.

If you had a single thing you wanted to update, it might make sense to wonder about finding a PPA that contains it in a version for Mint 20.3. However, you want to update multiple things (especially Python) that are very central to a lot of other software that depends on a specific version of them. In other words:

If you really want the latest version of all the software known to be maintained under Mint, get the latest version of Linux Mint. If you're a beginner, as you claim, you gain exactly nothing from newer versions, aside from them not being as well-tested.

Mint is a pretty large, pretty well-maintained distro. Unlike third-party PPAs, Mint actually promises security updates for the software they ship, without breaking your application. *Exactly* what you need to develop web applications. Don't fall prey to the idea that you always need to chase the latest version of PHP, Apache or MariaDB to be safe – you need one that has the latest security patches, which is what you get anyway.

So, the solution is actually: Unless you're actually in the business MODIFYING php, Python, Apache HTTPD,…, instead of USING these tools, daemons and languages, you don't need to do anything, and you **should** not do anything: For as long as Mint 20.3 is supported, you get the latest security updates.

Comment: I don't like "me-too" comments but I have to agree here. If you want the latest & greatest version of every package then you need to look at a distribution like gentoo or arch. Otherwise, Mint, Ubuntu, Alma, OEL, etc. will give you stable, reasonable current, and *supported* versions of each package. Wandering off into PPA territory with who-knows-what versions of a range of packages is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: … disaster, because a PPA's job is not to guarantee the rest of the system still works. "Here's a PPA that will give you a nightly built of `python`, it will definitely break all your system," is a perfectly legit and useful PPA (for developers that want to test what happens on nightly python without needing the rest of the system to still work), and it's completely useless for the part of the world that needs *working* systems. So, 100% on point, @doneal24.